# 8:40 arrival at Manchester - how much time will it take to leave the airport?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, manchester, man

Our plane from Orlando arrives at 8:40 and I wish to book my train tickets to travel home. Given that we have to go through customs and baggage collection, at what time are we likely to be out of the airport and at Manchester airport train station?

Comment: I just don't get the question?!

Comment: Are you arriving at 8:40am or 8:40pm?

Comment: Which Manchester?

Comment: @choster The one in England. I am quite sure [my local airport](http://www.flymanchester.com/) has no train station.

Comment: @neubert Looks like 8:40 AM on AA734. But the OP really should include these details.

Comment: Where are you getting your train to? You could just walk to the platform when you make it out and get the next train available. pay on the platform at the ticket machines?

Comment: Depends which passport you're travelling on more than anything

Comment: @MichaelHampton: 24-hour time is common in Britain, so I suspect to most British people, in the context of flight schedules, "8:40" unambiguously means AM.  The time 12 hours later would be "20:40".

Comment: Which terminal? Some take a lot longer to get to the station from than others.

Comment: Why not buy the tickets [online](http://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/to-and-from-the-airport/train/) using your smartphone while waiting for your baggage at the airport?

Comment: @CountIblis probably because at that point it's too late to get advance tickets that can save you a lot of money. If the OP lived in Manchester, its not that important, but they could live much further away.

Answer (score 1):

I have flown into Manchester many times. Sometimes it take forever to pass through immigration. From my experience it depends on what day of the week and time of the year. In summer, it will take longer for obvious reasons. Also, if you are not a EU citizen it will take longer to pass immigration.

With regards to baggage collection, Manchester is pretty good compared to some airports i have arrived at.

I normally allow 1.5 hours after the scheduled arrival time for booking onward travel. Flights don't always run on-time.